# How to merge records in collection

Tags: java, collections

I have collection what contain records:

```
[date_from, date_To, name]
```

I want to merge records if dates follow each other or dates contain a common part  also name should be the same. For example:

```
[10.07.2020, 31.07.2020, A], [01.08.2020, 11.08.2020, A], [09.08.2020, 15.08.2020, A], [20.08.2020, 05.09.2020, C], [14.09.2020, 16.09.2020, X], [17.09.2020, 19.09.2020, Y]
```

gives me result:

```
[10.07.2020, 15.08.2020, A], [20.08.2020, 05.09.2020, C], [14.09.2020, 16.09.2020, X], [17.09.2020, 19.09.2020, Y]
```

I'm thinking what will be the best way to do this in Java.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your code, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed as you need a unique record by name and dates should be most old to most latest. in the below code change the dates instead new to some specific and it should serve your need.

```
public class MultipleListingFromSIngle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<A> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    A one = new A(new Date(), new Date(), "krish");
    A one1 = new A(new Date(), new Date(), "krish");
    A one2 = new A(new Date(), new Date(), "krish");

    A two = new A(new Date(), new Date(), "two");
    A three = new A(new Date(), new Date(), "three");
    A four = new A(new Date(), new Date(), "four");
    lst.add(one);lst.add(two);lst.add(three);lst.add(four);lst.add(one1);lst.add(one2);
    List<String> namesList = lst.stream().map(A::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<A> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String name : namesList) {
        List<A> filteredList = lst.stream().filter(x -> x.getName().equals(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (filteredList.size() == 1) {
            finalList.addAll(filteredList);
        } else {
            Date minDate =null;
            Date maxDate=null;
            String name1 = null;
            for(A a1: filteredList) {
                if (minDate == null && maxDate== null) {
                    minDate=a1.getFromDate();
                    maxDate=a1.getToDate();
                    name1=a1.getName();
                } else {
                    if (minDate.after(a1.getFromDate())) {
                        minDate=a1.getFromDate();
                    }
                    if (maxDate.before(a1.getToDate())) {
                        maxDate=a1.getToDate();
                    }
                }
            }
            finalList.add(new A(minDate, maxDate, name1));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(finalList);
}
```

}

this is how I have assumed and created a pojo

```
class A {
Date fromDate;
Date toDate;
String name;

public Date getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
}

public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
}

public Date getToDate() {
    return toDate;
}

public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
    this.toDate = toDate;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public A(Date fromDate, Date toDate, String name) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
    this.toDate = toDate;
    this.name = name;
}

public A() {
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "A{" +
            "fromDate=" + fromDate +
            ", toDate=" + toDate +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}